# Heroku Build api issue

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-api

I am using the Heroku Build API as documented [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#build).

In the source blob, I am providing the git url for the repository

```
"source_blob": {
  "url": "https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started/archive/master.zip"
}
```

I am constantly seeing below error:

`Unable to fetch source from:https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started/archive/master.zip`

Any one able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without .zip

```
"source_blob": { 
"url": "https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started/archive/master"
}
```